# Quotient of sum of ideals

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

Suppose we have ideals $I_1, I_2$. Is there any way to simplify $(I_1+I_2)/I_1$?

I'm thinking since all elements are of the form $i_1+i_2+I_1$ it should be simplified to $I_2/I_1$ but since $I_1$ is not necessarily in $I_2$ I am confused.

Comment: As abelian group, this is isomorphic to $I_2/(I_1 \cap I_2)$.

Comment: @Watson What about as rings?

Comment: @Watson Right. I am still confused though, how does one construct the isomorphism?

Comment: See [the second isomorphism theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isomorphism_theorem#Noether.27s_Second_isomorphism_theorem) : look at $f : I_2 \to (I_1+I_2)/I_1$ defined by $f(x)=x+I_1$.

Comment: @Watson yes, thank you.

Comment: @Watson Ideals are (nonunital) subrings, and the quotient definitely has a ring structure. The only thing I can think of that sounds like what you're saying is that *subrings are not necessarily ideals*.

Comment: @rschwieb : I was thinking about unital subrings.

Comment: @Watson I know what you mean, but saying there's *no ring structure* when all that might be missing is an identity seems to be shortchanging it a lot. It definitely has *some* ring structure (all or nearly all, depending on definition, as you pointed out!)  Considering that everything goes through in the category of rings without unity, it seems a bit of a shame to cop out of the question by drawing the line at rings with identity and not mention this other nice aspect. That's what I mean, I guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As abelian group, this is isomorphic to $I_2/(I_1 \cap I_2)$, using [the second isomorphism theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isomorphism_theorem#Noether.27s_Second_isomorphism_theorem) : look at the group morphism
$$f : I_2 \to (I_1+I_2)/I_1$$ defined by $f(x)=x+I_1$.
Is it surjective? What is its kernel? Using the first isomorphism theorem
$$f/\ker(f) \cong \mathrm{im}(f)$$
you should get $I_2/(I_1 \cap I_2) \cong (I_1+I_2)/I_1$.

---

Notice that ideals are not subrings (in general), so there is no ring structure on your quotient. Then, it makes no sense to ask "What about as rings?".

---

You can however ask: is it an isomorphism of $R$-modules, where $I_1,I_2$ are ideals of a commutative ring $R$?

Comment: *Notice that ideals are not subrings (in general), so there is no ring structure on your quotient.* Hm? $(I_1+I_2)/I_1$ is an ideal of $R/I_1$, so it has a perfectly natural ring structure. Are you thinking of something else?

Comment: You are sorely mistaked, an ideal is a subring, abelian group and closed under multiplication and distributive over addition, those are all the qualities for a ring.

Comment: @ZelosMalum, rschwieb : I'm thinking about unital rings, and in general an ideal doesn't contain $1$.

Comment: @Watson Unital ring $\neq$ ring, but unital ring $\subset$ ring. If you say Unital ring you are correct, a proper ideal is never a unital ring. But all ideals are rings. and only one ideal is a unital ring and it is the entire ring.

Comment: @ZelosMalum : I agree, but what you call "ring" is what I call [rng](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rng_(algebra)). We didn't have the same definition of ring, that's all :-)

Comment: He was because it is known it was just meant as a joke, nothing else.